# Error when deploying my application

Tags: weblogic

i want deploy my application on my weblogic server so when i see the log i have this error

> **May 3, 2012 3:00:20 PM CEST Error Configuration Management BEA-150027 Server name integration not found in domain BUP.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the 'target' of the deployment is specified as 'integration' and there is no server with that name in your domain.  The target must be a server or cluster name that is configured for your domain.